# How I can validate parameters in Reader for my query

Tags: spring-batch

I need validate a parameters for my query inside a reader, i send the parameters inside the RunConfiguration, I give you my code job,thanks for your help (I censured part of code with "*" for the data proteccion)

```
<bean class="**.*****.absis.batch.arch.internal.reader.***ItemReader" id="readerBBDD_Step1">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource"></property>
    <property name="sql" value="select conf.repte, imp.IMPREPTE1 , imp.IMPREPTE2, imp.IMPREPTE3,imp.IMPREPTE4,imp.IMPREPTE5,imp.IMPREPTE6, subrepte, negocio, asignacion, tipus, origen  from **************BATCH0003 conf inner join 
TDE_IMPORTREPTES_BATCH0003 imp on CONF.REPTE = imp.repte 
where conf.anyo = imp.anyo and conf.repte = '****' and esquema = '*****' and tipus='${param1}'" ></property>    
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="****.****.absis.batch.arch.internal.reader.****sBaseRowMapper">
            <property name="rowMapper">
                <bean class="***.***.absis.batch.app.****.util.MapperStep1"></bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My goal is control the parameter1

Answer (score 1):

> i send the parameters inside the RunConfiguration

You can pass `param1` as a parameter to your job and validate it with a [`JobParametersValidator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#jobparametersvalidator).

Then, once it is validated, it can be passed to your reader with:

```
tipus='#{jobParameters[param1]}'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. You can explain me how I can use JobParametersValidator? and this: tipus='#{jobParameters[param1]}' Do I put it on my reader class right?

Comment: `JobParametersValidator` is an interface. You implement this interface with your validation logic then add your implementation to the job as shown in the link I gave (There is a toggle on the top of the page to choose between Java/XML config). Then replace `tipus='${param1}'` in your XML with `tipus='#{jobParameters[param1]}'`.

Comment: Last question, I create a new  independent class on my package with this import like :ValidatorParameters.java? or I do a import in a class configuration or something